# Bucle while solo me cargar el ultimo registro c# N Capas

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, vs

espero se encuentren bien, tengo una aplicación la cual quiero que me cargue atravesó de código simultáneamente una imagen y un texto dentro de un panel, quiero que esto se me repita dependiente del estado de los registro en la base de datos, en este caso solo lo que estén activos, consigo cargar todo bien, pero mi error es que solo me carga el ultimo registro activo que tengo en mi base de datos

Aqui mi codigo en la **CAPA DATOS**

```
    public CEUsuarios DATOSUSUAROS()
    {
        CEUsuarios obj = new CEUsuarios();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(}CDConexion.conectar))
            {
                conexion.Open();

                string query = "SELECT * FROM USUARIOS  WHERE estado = 1";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        obj = new CEUsuarios()
                        {
                            IdUsuario = Convert.ToInt32(dr["idUsuario"].ToString()),
                            NombreUsuario = dr["nombreUsuario"].ToString(),
                            Imagen = (byte[])dr["imagen"],
                            Estado = (bool)dr["estado"]
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            obj = new CEUsuarios();
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Luego en la **CAPA NEGOCIO**

```
public CEUsuarios DATOSUSUAROS()
    {
        CEUsuariosObjUsuario= ObjDatos.DATOSUSUAROS();
        return ObjUsuario;
    }
```

En el Label en su propiedad Text cargo de mi base de datos el ID y en su propiedad Name cargo el nombre y en el Picturebox cargo la imagen directamente

**FOMULARIO**

```
 public void MOSTRAR()
    {
        CEUsuarios ObjUsuarios = new CDUsuarios().DATOSUSUAROS();

        bool? checkState = (bool?)ObjUsuarios.Estado;
        while (checkState != null || checkState == true)
        {
            //Constructor................
            Label lblNombre = new Label();
            Panel pnlContenedor = new Panel();
            PictureBox ptbxImagen= new PictureBox();

            //Label.....
            lblNombre .Text = **ObjUsuarios.NombreUsuario.ToString();**
            lblNombre .Name = **ObjUsuarios.IdUsuario.ToString();**
            lblNombre .Size = new System.Drawing.Size(175, 25);
            lblNombre .Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 13);
            lblNombre .ForeColor = Color.White;
            lblNombre .Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
            lblNombre .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
       
            //Panel.....
            pnlContenedor.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(155, 167);
            pnlContenedor.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

            //PictureBox.....
            ptbxImagen.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(175, 132);
            ptbxImagen.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            ptbxImagen.BackgroundImage = null;

            byte[] bi = (Byte[])ObjUsuarios.Icono;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bi);
            ptbxImagen.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

            ptbxImagen.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            ptbxImagen.Tag = **ObjUsuarios.NombreUsuario.ToString();**
            ptbxImagen.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;

            //Agregar controles al Panel...........
            pnlContenedor.Controls.Add(lblNombre );
            pnlContenedor.Controls.Add(ptbxImagen);


            //Cargar datos al FlowLayoutPanel
            flowlayoutpanel1.Controls.Add(pnlContenedor);

            break;


        }

    }
```

Comment: Pues tu metodo ddice que regresas una instancia de `CEUsuarios`, y creas un objeto `CEUsuarios` que estas sobreescribiendo en cada iteracion del `dr.Read()` no deberias mejor que el metodo returne algun `IEnumerable<CEUsuarios>` o `List<CEUsuarios>` y que en cada iteracion del `dr.Read()` hagas un `Add()` a la lista con una nueva instancia de `CEUsuarios` ?, y que esta sea la que retornes

Comment: Muchas grACIAS @StialManstike por la ayuda, intente lo que me sugeriste pero igual me carga siempre el ultimo registro, algo estoy haciendo mal que solo me esta cargando el ultimo registro.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y coloca lo que intentaste respecto a la respuesta que dió Stial. Tal y como él te lo dice, lo único que haces ahora es iterar el resultado de la base de datos y crear un objeto CEUsuarios que se limpia en cada iteración, basicamente estas buscando N usuarios y estas creando un unico usuario, cuando la iteración termina, retorna el último usuario "creado", debes crear una lista de usuarios y llenarla con esos usuarios y retornar la lista. Tal y como lo dice Stial